# Offline Domain Join Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 domain, and I need to join a Windows Server 2003 machine to the domain. I have also lost any local user passwords to the 2003 machine.

Can I use Offline Domain Join to add the 2003 machine to the 2008 domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You messed it up.

This is not a problem of domain join.

You lost all passwords to the computer. How you expect to log in to join the domain?

If I could join a computer to a domain WITHOUT HAVING ADMINISTRATIVE ACCESS TO THE COMPUTER, this would be a hugh grave security issue (because I could give myself administrator priviledges through that).

Besides it does not work with a 2003 anyway. Use a password cracker.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. One of the sources of the issue was that the the 2003 computer was rebooted, and for some reason, it didn't reassociate to the domain (which it was associated to before the reboot).

Comment: OUCH ;) I had that once, too. Since then I keep local admin passwords always working, printed out weekly.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In reality, the passwords were lost (passive) when a key employee was let go.